# grab an word and wrap it returns type error

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I am trying to find a word and wrap it with `<span></span>`, i wrote:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $highLight = $('.info_vertical h1');
    $highLight.html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace('Use', '<span>Use</span>');
    });
});
</script>
```

But it returns with ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null***. Is this code ok? and how to resolve TypeError?

Comment: what does `$('.info_vertical h1')` returns. looks like `$highLight ` is empty

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/wurj9tnh/  So provide online sample to replicate your issue. BTW, which jquery version are you using? Is `$` referring to jQuery? Etc...

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Even a jQuery empty object is returned, this should failed silently, not throwing any error

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.11.2. is the problem of jQuery version?

Comment: No it isn't, any jq version >= 1.4 supports function as html method parameter and anyway, reading again your error message, this is unrelevant here. I guess, `$` isn't jQuery. Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`, does it fix your issue? Or instead use: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});` passing `$` as ready handler parameter, so now inside function context, `$ === jQuery`

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff, its done.